# How to make a SQL table bigger

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with 100 rows with double as data

```
a1 a2 a3...
---------
1  2   3
23 55  4
2  3   7
```

I am planning to use `UNION ALL` to make that table bigger

```
a1 a2 a3...
---------
1  2   3
23 55  4
2  3   7
1  2   3
23 55  4
2  3   7
1  2   3
23 55  4
2  3   7
```

This is for testing purposes so what do you recommend, what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: +1, interesting question.  Out of curiosity, is this for testing to see how queries perform on larger datasets than you currently have (before moving to production I suppose)?

Comment: Doubles...?  :-)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx

Comment: @jadarnel27: yes first to test with not so big datasets, and then bigger datasets

Comment: Clever, I really like the idea.  @kuru k: Ha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will increase the size of your table exponentially...  First it inserts x records, then 2x, then 4x, then 8x...  You could add `distinct` or `top n`, etc. to the select if you just want to add the same number of records each time.

```
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @max int

SET @count int = 1
SET @max = 10

WHILE @count < @max
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO myTable (a1, a2, a3)
   SELECT a1, a2, a3 FROM myTable
   SET @count = @count + 1
END
```

BTW -- not sure what you're trying to test, but you might add something besides whole numbers to your data set -- e.g., 1.01, .99, 55.7, 60, etc.

**EDIT**

Per your comment -- if you *really want* to use `union all` then...

```
INSERT INTO myTABLE (a1, a2, a3)
SELECT a1, a2, a3 FROM
(
SELECT a1, a2, a3 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT a1, a2, a3 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT a1, a2, a3 FROM myTable
...
) a
```

Comment: Are you trying to add more rows to the table, or are you trying to do something with `UNION ALL`? Do those things have to go together?

Comment: "I want to walk to Central Park." *"But sir, you're in Paris."* "I don't care, I want to walk."

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT dbo.Table
  SELECT /* TOP (n) */ t1.a1, t1.a2, t1.a3
  FROM       dbo.Table AS t1
  CROSS JOIN dbo.Table AS t2
-- repeat CROSS JOINs as necessary
```

The first cross join will square, second cross join will cube, etc. Luke @kuru's answer you can limit the number of rows added using TOP in case you don't want to do the math.